# Why does Fancybox's image loading take so long?

Tags: heroku, fancybox

I'm using fancybox.js to load my images. The smaller version of the images load very quickly, however, the large images (the ones that pop out in a modal) take anywhere from 4 to 10 seconds to load. My images are in the jpeg format, but I doubt that that's the problem. I'm hosting on Heroku -- could this be the culprit?

Comment: What happens if you try and load just that image on it's own?

Comment: Sorry, I may have been unclear.  When I select an image to pop outwards as a modal, that large image is what takes long to load.

Comment: How large are these images? (filesize)

Comment: @NeilMiddleton And with that comment, issue is resolved. I didn't think of that earlier because all the images loaded up by fancybox are resized to fit the window, which I thought were the original size of the photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess from what you are saying that the filesize of the images that you are seeing is quite large.  Remember that Fancybox resizes images to suit the viewport of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

A really silly mistake as I needed to resize my images.

I didn't think of this simple solution earlier because of deception.  All the images loaded up by fancybox are resized to fit the window, which I then thought were the original size of the photos.  Turns out that the images were at least 4 times the size of what is shown.